# Undefined name 'currentUser'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
am trying to create profile page that the auth user will see or appear to the user

```dart
//import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import 'package:yumor/models/user_model.dart';
//import 'package:yumor/pages/Home_page.dart';
//import 'package:yumor/pages/profile.dart';
//import 'package:yumor/pages/search.dart';
//import 'package:yumor/pages/upload.dart';

//class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  //const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  //@override
  //State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
//}

//class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  List pages = [
    home_page(),
    search(),
    upload(),
    profile(userProfile:currentUser?.uid),
  ];
//  this current index means that this index depends on which one you click form 0 to 4
 
~~~!
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebase Auth:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid
```

Comment: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' this what appeared to me when i used fireAuth cause i defined userProfile as final String

Comment: If you are sure a user is logged-in then use it like this: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid